# Why is my average calculated output printing at the wrong time?

Tags: python, loops, average

Trying to get the average from values returned in a for loop and print it next to group name. I can get it to calculate the average and print it under the return but not next to the first print as in Group 2...

When I add the argument as in Group 2, I get this error:

```
    print "Group 2 - %s%%" % (avg)
NameError: name 'avg' is not defined
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, please help. If anyone has an easier way to do this please feel free to suggest.

The end result I'm looking for should be as follows:

```
Group 1 - 100%
name1    100
name2    100
name3    100

Group 2 - 100%
name1    100
name2    100
name3    100
```

Here is my script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import json
import pycurl
import time
from io import BytesIO

# Which monitors should data be retrieved for?
grp1 = ['000000000000000000', '000000000000000000', '000000000000000000']
grp2 = ['000000000000000000', '000000000000000000', '000000000000000000']

# Make calls to get the availability details
def connectMethod(method, url):
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    connectReturn = BytesIO()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: authtoken 00000000000000000000000000000000"])
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, connectReturn.write)
    c.setopt (pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, method)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
    connectOutput = connectReturn.getvalue()
    return connectOutput

returned_items = {}
avail = list()

print "Group 1"
for item in group1:
    base_url = 'https://www.domain.com/api/reports/summary/'
    putData = item + '?period=13&unit_of_time=1'
    req_url = base_url + putData
    listOfAvail = json.loads(connectMethod('GET', req_url))
    returned_items[item] = listOfAvail
    name = listOfAvail['data']['info']['resource_name']
    avail_pct = listOfAvail['data']['summary_details']['availability_percentage']
    avg_avail = avail.append(avail_pct)
    print "%s\t%s%%" % (name, avail_pct)

avg = float(sum(avail))/len(avail)
print avg

print "Group 2 - %s%%" % (avg)
for item in group2:
    base_url = 'https://www.domain.com/api/reports/summary/'
    putData = item + '?period=13&unit_of_time=1'
    req_url = base_url + putData
    listOfAvail = json.loads(connectMethod('GET', req_url))
    returned_items[item] = listOfAvail
    name = listOfAvail['data']['info']['resource_name']
    avail_pct = listOfAvail['data']['summary_details']['availability_percentage']
    avg_avail = avail.append(avail_pct)
    print "%s\t%s%%" % (name, avail_pct)

avg = float(sum(avail))/len(avail)
print avg
```

Comment: So, you are getting that error even though `print avg` works fine in the previous line?

Comment: You should be getting the undefined error with `group1` and `group2`, as they're named `grp1` and `grp2` up top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Quick, dirty, and ugly, but it should point you in the right direction to get it figured out and cleaned up a bit.

I just modified your code to output what you're asking for.
*(I hard coded the names and percentages where you're invoking the web call)*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import json
import pycurl
import time
from io import BytesIO

# Which monitors should data be retrieved for?
group1 = ['000000000000000000', '000000000000000000', '000000000000000000']
group2 = ['000000000000000000', '000000000000000000', '000000000000000000']

# Make calls to get the availability details
def connectMethod(method, url):
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    connectReturn = BytesIO()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: authtoken 00000000000000000000000000000000"])
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, connectReturn.write)
    c.setopt (pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, method)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
    connectOutput = connectReturn.getvalue()
    return connectOutput

def pprint(title, names, averages):
    avg = float(sum(percentages))/len(percentages)
    print "%s - %s%%" % (title, avg)
    for i in range(len(names)):
        print "%s\t%s" % (names[i], percentages[i])


returned_items = {}
percentages = []
names = []

for item in group1:
    base_url = 'https://www.domain.com/api/reports/summary/'
    putData = item + '?period=13&unit_of_time=1'
    req_url = base_url + putData
    #listOfAvail = json.loads(connectMethod('GET', req_url))
    returned_items[item] = {"name": "item 1" }  #listOfAvail
    name = "blah"  # listOfAvail['data']['info']['resource_name']
    avail_pct = 60  # listOfAvail['data']['summary_details']['availability_percentage']
    names.append(name)
    percentages.append(avail_pct)

pprint("Group 1", names, percentages)
print("")


del percentages[:]
del names[:]
for item in group2:
    base_url = 'https://www.domain.com/api/reports/summary/'
    putData = item + '?period=13&unit_of_time=1'
    req_url = base_url + putData
    #listOfAvail = json.loads(connectMethod('GET', req_url))
    returned_items[item] = {"name": "item 2" }  #listOfAvail
    name = "asdf"  #listOfAvail['data']['info']['resource_name']
    avail_pct = 87  #listOfAvail['data']['summary_details']['availability_percentage']
    names.append(name)
    percentages.append(avail_pct)

pprint("Group 1", names, percentages)
```

This outputs:

```
Group 1 - 60.0%
blah    60
blah    60
blah    60

Group 1 - 87.0%
asdf    87
asdf    87
asdf    87
```

Essentially you just need to perform all your calculations first, and then print the results.

---

Some thoughts to help you clean this up a bit

**Code Reuse**:
The code in the `for` loops is nearly identical. Refactor this into a function where you pass the `group`, `url`, etc. *(does this make sense)*?

Have a look into the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, it could condense your web call code quite a bit.

Comment: thanks for the reply. This points me in the right direction. I got the averages to work however One of them seems to be outputting longer than 2 decimal places.

    name1 99.99%
    name2 99.99%
    name3 100.0%
    name4 100.0%
    name5 99.99%
    name6 99.99%
    name7 100.0%
    Group Average 99.9942857143%`

I tried wrapping the avg calculation in a format but that did not work...

    avg = round(float(sum(percentages))/len(percentages),2)

I am still attempting to figure it out on my own so no rush on another point for now.

Comment: Never mind.. I forgot to clear the percentages before I started that group.. All good now.

Thanks again.